# Examples of complex analysis useful in optimization?

Tags: complex-analysis, optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Are there any examples of complex analysis applicable to mathematical optimization problems (preferably non-linear optimization)?

I am wondering what advantages the use of complex numbers would have in optimization problems.

Comment: Usually it comes up more in the theoretical underpinnings. As an example, the behavior of a matrix-related method is often tied to conditions on eigenvalues, which we generally think of as complex numbers.

Comment: but the spectral radius is always a real number...

Comment: https://lirias.kuleuven.be/bitstream/123456789/342824/2/complex_optimization.pdf could be of interest.

Comment: Sure, but how do you find the spectral radius of $\pmatrix{0&-1\\1&0}$, for example